# Chrome: Add sites to new tab page

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome 20.

I deleted a bunch of sites from my new tabs page. But they're not getting refilled. It's been a few weeks but I see 3 empty grey boxes. Anyway to fill them?

Answer (score -1):

This probably means that Chrome is not storing history. Check your settings or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see if your history is being populated.

Theres also an article over at [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5684600/refresh-google-chromes-most-visited-thumbnails) that explains how to do a refresh of the new tab page

Comment: very strange. In that case your easiest option might be a reinstall